# How to handle size issue in feign.okhttpclient

Tags: java, okhttp, micronaut, feign

I have an API declared in MicroNaut and writing component-tests for it. For this purpose, I have declared a APIHelper which is an interface and have definitions for all the api and initiate it using:

```
return Feign.builder()
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .target(ApiHelper.class, serviceUrl);
```

In the API Resource File, we send response like:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpResponse
                    .ok(response);
```

The issue is, whenever the size of the response is large, when I do Response.body().toString() in the test, I get feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1@xxxx instead of the data, but when the size is small, it works fine, how to fix this